# Grab title from external url web page

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I'm trying to get the title of a external Url Web Page

In my view I use the following script

```
 <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){                     
            $(function(){
                $("#grabUrl").click(function(e){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('post/geturl', array('url' => 'http://bbc.co.uk)); ?>",


                    success: function(data) {


                    // How can I get the content of the title tag? or the favicon ?                         }   
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

my controller action simply does

```
public function actionGetUrl($url)
{
    $str = file_get_contents($url);
    return $str;


}
```

What should I put inside my function data to get the title and favicon ?

Comment: is your controller in php ?

Comment: actionGetUrl  is in my PostController @johnSmith

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
$title = $html->find('title', 0)->innertext;
$html->clear(); //important
```

`echo $title;`

Comment: Even better, get the Yii extension here: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/simplehtmldom/

Answer (score 0):

if you just wanted to pass the title i would rather write this php,
sure you could do the same thing in js

```
public function actionGetUrl($url)
{
    $str = file_get_contents($url);
    // index of the opening-tag + the length of needle
    $openTag = strpos($str,"<title>") +7;
    // index of the ending tag
    $endTag = strpos($str,"<\/title>");
    // extract the bit between
    $title = substr($str, $openTag, ($endTag - $openTag));

    return $title;
}
```

this is not tested, but you should get an idea how to extract information , you should build in some error-handling too

cheers

updated, the same in js :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('post/geturl', array('url' => 'http://bbc.co.uk)); ?>",
    success: function(data) {
        strang= String(data);
        openTag = strang.indexOf("<title>") +7 ;
        endTag = strang.indexOf("<\/title>");
        title = strang.substring(openTag,endTag)
        alert(title);
    }   
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  But how can I use it within my jquery script  for example  with alert ?   alert(data)  does not work @johnsmith

Comment: you have to debug yourself, could you just log console.log(data) to see what response you get ?= rather that one is empty